# Como consigo pegar o nome da máquina via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá, gostaria de pegar o nome da máquina do usuário que está acessando minha aplicação.. Como posso fazer isso por javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nomepc(){
        var net = new ActiveXObject("wscript.network");
        alert(net.UserDomain + ': ' + net.ComputerName);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: estas a usar nodejs ? pois este tem uma funcao que te permite fazer isso

Comment: Esse comando só funciona em IE, e nem todas versões. O nome da máquina não é possível obter pelo cliente.

Comment: @ScrapBench, Como posso fazer em nodejs? você tem algum exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

```
    require('dns').reverse(req.connection.remoteAddress', function(err, domains) {

    console.log(domains);
});
```

Pra dar seguimento ao comentario da pergunta usando esta funcao o teu server vai fazer um reverse DNS e em principio deve funcionar